# is there any way to control system volume from a app in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I downloaded a app named "aurio Touch" from apple for ios platform. It captures the background sound using microphone and plays it simulteniously with other media sound (like, itunes songs, online songs etc). I want to control the capturing sound volume and media sound volume separately. so, Here is my question that is that possible or not. if possible then how can it achieved. 
Please help. 
Advance Thanks.....

Comment: Which OS? Is the question about the sample code "aurioTouch"?

Comment: it's for ios platform. mobile app.I have edited my post. Yes, I use "aurio Touch" sample code try to do that thing. try to control the volume of captured sound and system sound differently.